# JsTree drag between two trees and link?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, tree, jstree

I want to use JsTree (or rather, that's the one I'm trying with right now), to have 2 trees. You should be able to drag and drop nodes, but NOT within the tree, only between the trees. And the node should not move or get copied, it should create a relationship, i.e I assume this would be achieved by a callback, because the tree doesn't have to register the relationship itself, all I need is to get the info that e.g Child Node A has been dropped on Child Node 1.

Here's what I have so far just from the samples on the JsTree site, basically just two dnd trees, which is not good enough, because you cannot currently drag between the trees, and also you can drag within, which again you should not be allowed to in my scenario (the html is just that I put it in a Bootstrap sample page):

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>

            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
                condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis
                euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>

            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>


            <div id="jstree">
                <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
                <ul>
                    <li>Root node start
                        <ul>
                            <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
                            <li>Child node 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Root node 2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>

            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
                condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis
                euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>

            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>

            <div id="jstree2">
                <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
                <ul>
                    <li>Root node start
                        <ul>
                            <li id="child_node_1_2">Child node A</li>
                            <li>Child node B</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Root node 2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>

            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula
                porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut
                fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>

            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the jquery (again mainly from the samples):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $('#jstree').jstree({
        "core":{
            "animation":0,
            "check_callback":true,
            "themes":{ "stripes":true }
        },
        rules:{
            droppable:[ "tree-drop" ],
            multiple:true,
            deletable:"all",
            draggable:"all"
        },
        "types":{
            "#":{
                "max_children":1,
                "max_depth":4,
                "valid_children":["root"]
            },
            "root":{
                "icon":"/static/3.0.0-beta5/assets/images/tree_icon.png",
                "valid_children":["default"]
            },
            "default":{
                "valid_children":["default", "file"]
            },
            "file":{
                "icon":"glyphicon glyphicon-file",
                "valid_children":[]
            }
        },
        "plugins":[
            "contextmenu", "dnd", "search",
            "state", "types", "wholerow"
        ]
    });

    $('#jstree2').jstree({
            "core":{
                "animation":0,
                "check_callback":true,
                "themes":{ "stripes":true }
            },
            rules:{
                droppable:[ "tree-drop" ],
                multiple:true,
                deletable:"all",
                draggable:"all"
            },
            "types":{
                "#":{
                    "max_children":1,
                    "max_depth":4,
                    "valid_children":["root"]
                },
                "root":{
                    "icon":"/static/3.0.0-beta5/assets/images/tree_icon.png",
                    "valid_children":["default"]
                },
                "default":{
                    "valid_children":["default", "file"]
                },
                "file":{
                    "icon":"glyphicon glyphicon-file",
                    "valid_children":[]
                }
            },
            "plugins":[
                "contextmenu", "dnd", "search",
                "state", "types", "wholerow"
            ]
        });

    // bind to events triggered on the tree
    $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
        console.log(data.selected);
    });

});
```

Comment: Hey! Looking to do something similar! Have you managed to find the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - get the latest source from github. You have to use the `check_callback` option and set it to a function as described here: http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=check_callback&f=$.jstree.defaults.core.check_callback

In the callback make sure you only allow multitree moves (inspect the arguments you receive in the callback and pass them to `$.jstree.reference(obj / par)._id`. You'd want to make sure parent and node are from different trees. Only then return `true`.

Make sure you do not allow any `delete_node` operations, and listen for a `copy_node.jstree` event on the receiving tree - once that fires - delete the newly copied node and create your relationship.

The other way to approach this is by building your own plugin using `jstree.dnd.js` as a base. That would probably be better, but it will take more time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand your answer. I don't know how to make sure not to allow any delete_node operations and so on... For now I decided to just use the tree functionality and none of the dnd. I opted for html5 dnd because it was easier for me to understand.